# How to add a delay on load screen for 2 sec and then continue on whatever time it takes to load?

Tags: javascript, css, delay, loading

- Hey guys I want my screen loader to show a 2sec delay even if the internet connection is fast.
- And then after at least 2 sec loading time it will show the main page
- And if the internet is too slow then it should continue loading until the main screen appears.
- I want this because the loading screen is itself a part of my brand, and I've designed it pretty interesting. and its a GIF.
- this uses HTML, CSS and JS see the code below. Thanks!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var loader = document.querySelector(".loader-wrapper");window.addEventListener("load", vanish);function vanish() {loader.classList.add("disappear");}
</script>
```

```css
.loader-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(3, 3, 3);
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10;
}
.loader img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: loader 2s ;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.disappear{animation: vanish 0.3s forwards;}
@keyframes vanish {100%{opacity: 0;visibility: hidden;}}
```

```html
<div class="loader-wrapper">
    <span class="loader"><img src="images/loadgif.gif"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) you can *wait* for something to happen before continuing your code. In your case you'll want to wait for the load event to happen and for 2 seconds to pass. With [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) you could wait for both these promises to resolve and only continue of both those scenario's occur.

```
/**
 * Promise that resolves whenever the load event fires.
 */
const pageLoad = new Promise(resolve => {
    window.addEventListener('load', resolve);
});

/**
 * Promise that resolves after 2 seconds.
 */
const delayTimeout = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
});

/**
 * Wait for both the pageLoad and delayTimeout to resolve.
 */
Promise.all([pageLoad, delayTimeout]).then(() => {
  // Show page.
  vanish();
});
```